# Aggregration and unique table row in javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

item no.         | depertment                 | qty

1                   Dept 1                       1

2                   Dept1                       5

3                   Dept2                       10

4                   Dept2                        5

5                   Dept3                        5

6                   Dept1                        6

and I want it to look like this

item no.          | item description                     | qty
1                          Dept1                                  12
2                            Dept2                                  15
3                               Dept3                                   5

### Heading

---

Comment: Welcome to stackover!!  Please take a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks! Also please clean up your image posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can mostly accomplish this in SharePoint by modifying the view.

Set the view to "Group By" the column with your identifier (`depertment` in your example), and in the "Totals" section tell it to show the Sum of your quantity column (`qty` in your example).

This will display the records in a "collapsed" view, grouping them by department and showing the number of grouped items in parentheses. Unfortunately, only when you expand a group will you see the sum of the field(s) you specified.

Comment: Thanks  you  for  you answer. but i  did the same with array